# Is it possible to create use the WebAudio API to analyze sound playing in the browser without an MP3 file?

Tags: javascript, audio, javascript-audio-api

I want to use the Web Audio API `AnalyserNode` without access to an MP3 source file. I'd like to just analyze the sound playing from the browser. Is that possible?

Comment: From where in the browser is that sound playing? To answer the implied question, No there is no way for non-chrome scripts to access every sound a browser can produce without user intervention. If you wish to do it only for you, then yes, there are ways, involving using a VirtualAudioDevice and routing your browser's default sink to this VAD's input while using the VAD's output as microphone while using getUserMedia, or building a browser extension. But it's not something you can expect any web-surfer will do.

Comment: @Kaiido the audio is coming from a website I’m making, but I’m using an API to stream the audio and I don’t have access to the audio file

Comment: Is the stream same-orign? I.e does it come from your server, or do you have a crossOrigin attribute on the element playing it? In that case all you need is a [MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode) or if served as a MediaStream, a [MediaStreamAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode). Otherwise, read my previous comment.